# How to write a generic function that takes a generic that implements a class that takes in other generics

Tags: scala, generics

```
  def recordToType[A <: TBase[T, F]](record: ConsumerRecord[String, Array[Byte]]): A = {
    (new TDeserializer(new TCompactProtocol.Factory())).deserialize(new A[T, F](), record.value())
  }
```

The above syntax doesn't work but basically I want A to be restricted to TBase but TBase requires two type parameters. If I leave those parameters out it says the parameters are required, if I put in the parameters it says the parameters are unresolved... What is the correct way to write this?

Comment: Just add the additional type parameter to the list: `def recordToType[T, F, A <: TBase[T, F]]`

Comment: That `new A[T, F]()` isn't going to compile because the constructor could take arguments (and it should be just `new A()` anyway). You should consider using a typeclass for this problem, with a factory method to create new instances.

Comment: Can you please provide us a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your method's signature like:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

def recordToType[T, F, A[_, _] <: TBase[T, F]](record: ConsumerRecord[String, Array[Byte]]): A[T,F]
```

but there's another problem with your code. You can't just create a new instance of generic type like this:

```
new A[T, F]
```

It will show an error similar to: `Error:(15, 9) class type required but A[T,F] found`

You cant capture class of `A` with implicit `ClassTag` though:

```
 def recordToType[T, F, A[_, _] <: TBase[T, F]](record: ConsumerRecord[String, Array[Byte]])(
    implicit m: scala.reflect.ClassTag[A[_,_]]
  ): A[T,F] = {
   val a:A[T,F] = m.runtimeClass.getConstructors.head.newInstance().asInstanceOf[A[T, F]]
   ...
```